# Toggle Button inside a canvas

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a canvas object in my xaml that has a togglebutton and two textblocks, like this.

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate >
      <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="485" 
              Margin="-15,0,-15,80" Visibility="Visible" 
              MouseLeftButtonUp="MandantenStackPanel_MouseLeftButtonDown">
         <ToggleButton Name="FavToggle" Checked="FavChecked" Unchecked="FavUnchecked"
                       Style="{StaticResource CustomToggleButtonStyle}" 
                       Foreground ="White" BorderBrush="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                       Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Icons/favs.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" >
            </ImageBrush>
         </ToggleButton>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding MandantenNummer}" FontSize="24" 
                    TextWrapping="Wrap" Canvas.Left="90" Canvas.Top="20"/>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding MandantenBezeichnung}" FontSize="24" 
                    TextWrapping="Wrap" Canvas.Left="90" Canvas.Top="50"/>
      </Canvas>
   </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

In my .cs i am binding a collection item to that listbox that also has a boolean called isFavorite that i'd like to toggle with my togglebutton. How can i access the data context from the canvas from inside my toggle event handlers? I tried it like i did it like i do it when you click on the textbox:

```cs
private void FavChecked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClassX x = (sender as Canvas).DataContext as Class x;
            x.isFavorite = true;
        }
```

but that of course doesn't work cause my sender is the togglebutton and not the canvas. Can i access the canvas from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sender` is `ToggleButton` and not `Canvas` because that is the control on which you attached that event handler.

Also, DataContext is set recursively so ToggleButton inherits the same data context the parent has.